# Collectionview in NSObject Class doesn't work?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsobject

I wrote a class contain a collectionview to show in main viewcontroller,
but it was "never" shows the cell data. And the cell background color wasn't change to black..(change color is only for test, not my purpose)..
(The collectionView can be showed correctly)
Where I should to correct it?

```
class CellClass: NSObject,
                 UICollectionViewDataSource,
                 UICollectionViewDelegate,
                 UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    
    let cellid = "cellid"
    
    let cv : UICollectionView = {
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let v = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,
                                 collectionViewLayout: fl)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return v
    }()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("init")
        
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.register(Cell.self,
                    forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellid)
        
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        
            window.addSubview(cv)
            cv.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                              y: window.frame.height - 300,
                              width: window.frame.width,
                              height: 300)
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfItemsInSection")
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("cell")
        let vc = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellid,
                                                    for: indexPath) as! Cell
        vc.lbl.text = "test"
        vc.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return vc
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
    }

}


class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let lbl : UILabel = {
        let t = UILabel()
        t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return t
    } ()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        lbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                           y: 0,
                           width: 200,
                           height: 30)
        addSubview(lbl)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your `CellClass` from the view controller ? Please can you add that code ?

Comment: Thank's for Shawn Frank , it's only one line code "CellClass() ", to call it.

Comment: Sure, but from where and how do you call / instantiate it is what is important.

Comment: I call it from viewDidLoad in the main ViewController after other UI setup,

Comment: Oh! it's really works fine! My conecpt is totally not right, this is  too hard for me now. Thank you Shawn Frank!

Comment: Mach, no problem .. happy to help. Maybe if you find this complex, just make it a bit simple and add collection view directly to view controller. Get things working then move to complex topics. Anyways, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I have a feeling you do something like this in your `viewDidLoad`

```
let cellClass = CellClass()
```

As soon as the didLoad function completes its execution, `cellClass` no longer persists in order to be the datasource and delegate.

You can try this by adding a `deinit` to your `CellClass`

```
deinit {
    print("Cell Class Deinit")
}
```

And I believe it will be called

What I suggest instead is to `persist` the object beyond `viewDidLoad`

```
class AVPlayerScroll: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    var cellClass: CellClass?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cellClass = CellClass()
    }
```

I believe this should give you the results you are looking for

Comment: Perfect this ended up being the case for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try couple of things here.

1. You can either try to set the constraints programmatically. Something like this.

> NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
> lbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
> lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
> lbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
> actionSheetView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)])

2. You can try to assign the frame to the UILabel (lbl) subview in **layoutSubviews()** method.